# Apple Push Notification Feedback Service - how frequently does it check

Tags: objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been able to successfully create push notifications and I have also received responses from the feedback service, so I am confident that my configuration is correct, but I was wondering, how long after a device has been made inactive, will it be picked up by the Apple Push Notification Service.

When I first polled the feedback service, I received details on devices which were inactive several days ago.  Now, while testing, when I uninstall the application and occasionally poll the feedback service, I'm not receiving any results.

Any idea on how long it takes to update would be useful, as I'm no longer sure if the issue is else where in my code or if I'm just testing too soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Issues with Using the Feedback Service**

If you remove your app from your device and then send a push notification to it, you would expect to have the device token rejected, and the invalidated device token should appear on the feedback service. However, if this was the last push-enabled app on the device, it will not show up in the feedback service. This is because deleting the last app tears down the persistent connection to the push service before the notice of the deletion can be sent.

You can work around this by leaving at least one push-enabled app on the device in order to keep the persistent connection up. Just install any free push-enabled app from the App Store and you should then be able to delete your app and see it appear in the feedback service.

source:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2010/tn2265.html#TNTAG34

Comment: wow - weird behavior - that saved me from and endless quest around my tail to figure out why a specific device did not worked.
BTW - if you install a 3rdParty push enabled app after you have uninstalled your app (Which was the last at the time) and send push to your app - you will get the feedback successfully !

Comment: I have some follow up question - once your app is released to the app store...how would you continue develop future version of your app while this mecahnsim is in place? i have noticed that if i send feedback request from my dev machine it steals all my feedback from the production environment - i am not using DEV push on my dev environement  - because i have several environments like that (DEV,QA,STAGING) and etc... and i need my testers to have ad-hoc verstions of my app (to be as close to real life testing as possible)

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation elsewhere, I discovered people suggesting that for testing feedback service, there should be two instances of the app on the iPhone. Test the feedback service by removing 1 of these and then attempt to send notifications to this removed app. 
When I do this, the feedback service responds very quickly.

I do not have exact timings, but on my system, it feels like it is responding straight away after I make a call to attempt to push a notification and then immediately make a call to the feedback service.

Comment: Can you please provide links to your investigation elsewhere. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, shortly after posting this response, my hard drive crashed and I lost all my bookmarks, so could not post the relevant link. Daniels answer is spot on!