# PHP Push notification service, feedback is empty

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, feedback

The push works just fine, the problem is that the feedback is empty. I need to delete the tokens that have expired or have an invalid status.
Here is my push code:

```
// Push code example
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificateName);
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result) {
    echo '<p>The message has not been sent '. PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo '<p>The message has been sent  ' . PHP_EOL;
}

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

And for the feedback code I have tried
1.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificateName);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
// assume the private key passphase was removed.
// stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
// production server is ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196

if (!$fp) {
    //echo "Failed to connect feedback server: $err $errstr\n";
    return;
} else {
  // echo "Connection to feedback server OK\n";
}

echo "APNS feedback results\n";
while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38)) {
    $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon); 
    $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
    $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8)); 
    $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime); 
    $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4)); 
    $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
    echo "TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate . "\n";
    echo "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken. "\n\n";
}
fclose($fp);
```

and the result is empty.

2.
    // set default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Using Autoload all classes are loaded on-demand
//require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';
$feedback = new ApnsPHP_Feedback(
    ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
    $certificateName
);

// Connect to the Apple Push Notification Feedback Service
$feedback->connect();

$aDeviceTokens = $feedback->receive();
if (!empty($aDeviceTokens)) {
    var_dump($aDeviceTokens . '<br><br>');
}



// Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Feedback Service
$feedback->disconnect();
```

Also with an empty result

3.

// create context stream
$stream_context = stream_context_create();

```
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certificateName);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $errcode, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);
if (!$apns) {
    echo "ERROR $errcode: $errstr\n";
} else {
    $feedback_tokens = array();
    //and read the data on the connection:
    while (!feof($apns)) {
        $data = fread($apns, 38);
        if (strlen($data)) {
            $feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
        }
    }
    var_dump($feedback_tokens);
```

Also with an empty result.... please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple sandbox feedback server seems to return no inactive tokens, although production environment seems to be working fine.
Have a look at this thread: [Apple Push Notification Feedback Service - how frequently does it check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882293/apple-push-notification-feedback-service-how-frequently-does-it-check)

Suggested solution is to have two development apps on your device and then to delete one. The deleted one should appear in the list of inactive tokens.

Comment: this is also what i noticed. After some time the it just worked... weird apple. Thank you